# Bot Framework API: Skype and Skype for Business channel Id

Tags: bots, botframework, skype-for-business

I'm developing the web hook for a bot that has to support Skype and Skype for Business channels. 
Does anyone know what is the channel id of a Skype for Business activity? 
I need to distinguish between Skype and Skype for Business activities.

Is there a list of all currently supported channel ids?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The channel id for Skype for Business is `skypeforbusiness` per the example of the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/skype-for-business-bot-framework/docs/overview#feature-support).

Others channel ids can be found in the [ChannelIds](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/develop/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/ConnectorEx/IChannelCapability.cs#L39)  class.